# Audio file does not play - Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I have my audio file in MyProjectName_data\resources\Sounds\ but after btn click alert:"finished". play doas not starts.I am working on android

```
function page1_btn_OnPressed(e) {
SMF.Multimedia.playSound("myaudio.mp3",
true,false,
function(){alert("started to play...");},
function(){alert("finished...");});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue about playing audio files. 
It will be fixed in the upcoming releases of Smartface.